# What does "alleged" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Can any one explain me what "alleged" means. So many times, I come across this word, but I only found the meaning of it saying that it is a statement without a proof. I am a bit confused when I come across this word.

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the "adjectival" usage, as in *The alleged thief claimed that he was innocent?* In such contexts, it means *the person who was said [by potentially unreliable sources] to be a thief*. It's often interchangeable with ***so-called***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers what is the difference between alleged and allegedly??

Comment: @FumbleFingers what is the difference between alleged,allegedly and allegations

Comment: ***Alleged*** is a past participle verb (that can also be used "adjectivally", as per my earlier example). ***Allegedly*** is an adverb, used in contexts such as *The Jack of Hearts allegedly stole the tarts*. And ***allegations*** is a plural noun. You can look all this up in dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you've tried the dictionary.

Alleged means as yet not proved usually in an official way. An example:  The accuser *alleges* that the boy stole the bread. The accuser is the only witness and the bread is missing. Until and unless there is more proof, the boy is assumed to have stolen the bread, but he cannot be punished until then.

The crime also may not have happened at all. That would make the crime *alleged*.The accuser thinks but does not know for certain that there were six loaves but does know that now there are five loaves.